# Symfony2: How to design a resolve state by zip functionality on an address entity

Tags: php, symfony

This is rather a design question. I have an address entity with a ZIP field.

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* Address
*
* @ORM\Table(name="address")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Address 
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
 */
private $street;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="street2", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
 */
private $street2;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="zip", type="string", length=64, nullable=false)
 */
private $zip;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="city", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
 */
private $city;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=128, nullable=false)
 */
private $country;

 /**
 * Set city
 *
 * @param string $city
 * @return Address
 */
public function setCity($city)
{
    $this->city = $city;
    return $this;
}
    
/**
 * Get city
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCity()
{
    return $this->city;
}

 /**
 * Set country
 *
 * @param string $country
 * @return Address
 */
public function setCountry($country)
{
    $this->country = $country;
    return $this;
}
    
/**
 * Get country
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCountry()
{
    return $this->country;
}

 /**
 * Set street
 *
 * @param string $street
 * @return Address
 */
public function setStreet($street)
{
    $this->street = $street;
    return $this;
}
    
/**
 * Get street
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getStreet()
{
    return $this->street;
}

 /**
 * Set street2
 *
 * @param string $street2
 * @return Address
 */
public function setStreet2($street2)
{
    $this->street2 = $street2;
    return $this;
}
    
/**
 * Get street2
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getStreet2()
{
    return $this->street2;
}

 /**
 * Set zip
 *
 * @param string $zip
 * @return Address
 */
public function setZip($zip)
{
    $this->zip = $zip;
    return $this;
}
    
/**
 * Get zip
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getZip()
{
    return $this->zip;
}

}
```

In addition I have a geo database which I can use to resolve the state for a given zip.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `zipcode` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `district_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `zipcode` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8262 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `city` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `county_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `lat` float NOT NULL,
  `lng` float NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=12241 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `state` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=17 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

SELECT state.name
FROM zipcode
left join city on zipcode.city_id = city.id 
left join state on city.state_id = state.id
WHERE zipcode.zipcode = '26123'
```

I guess I want to have a getState() on the address entity. But I'm unsure in which way to design the database query. Does it make sense to create separate entities for the geo db? Or just create a helper function somewhere? Native sql calls?

Comment: From a non php developer I got the hint to create a singleton class for the geodata that implements the lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's fine for me, you will put your function which queries the state name in your zipcode entity repository. Apparentely you need other data, like lat lng ,... so it makes sense to create 3 seperate entities yes.

so you just have to do in the controller :

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository('AcmeMyBundle:Adresse');
$state = $repository->getState($zipcode);
```

and in adresse repository something which will look like

```
public function getState($zipCode)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a') 
        ->select('a','z','c','s')
        ->leftJoin('a.zip', 'z') 
        ->leftJoin('z.city', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('c.state', 's')
        ->where('a.zip = :zipcode')->setParameter('zipcode', $zipCode);

   return $qb->getResult();
}
```

The function you wrote would go in ZipCodeRepository,it's fine too, and makes one less join to do, but you asked for AdressRepository so your choice.

...on a side note , i had to do this to but i used google geolocalisation api, which was very convenient (converts whatever you have zipcode, street adress, .. into whatever you want ) , but it may not be what you are looking for!

hope i somehow helped you

Answer (score 2):

You need to define service. Let it be `GeoHelper`, inject ZipRepository in it and define method for converting ZIP into state name:

```
public function getStateByZip($zip)
{
    return $zipRepository->findBy(array('zipcode' => $zip))->getState();
}
```